# How can I hide the authoring information?

Tags: 8, layout-builder

Normally I would just click manage display and disable authoring information from showing, but with layout builder enabled, I don't have this option. I only have the Manage Layout option, which doesn't contain any way to disable the authoring information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable this information in content type settings.

[image: Editing of a content type]